# What is the connector on this laptop hard disk drive called?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a ten year old internal hard disk from a now useless laptop. I want to find a case/converter to use it like an external USB drive. There are loads of these for desktop (2.5in) drives, but I can't seem to find any that appear to be compatible with my hard disk,
which has an unusual connector:

[image]

[image]

It looks nothing [like the types shown here](http://m.sparepartswarehouse.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sparepartswarehouse.com%2FLaptopHardDriveInfo.htm&utm_referrer=#2847).

So the question is: What is this connector called, and is it even possible to find a USB case for it?

Comment: Originally from a HP laptop, if that helps.

Comment: If I am not mistaking, that is just something that is plugged into the SATA port of the HDD, to allow easier insertion / removal from the laptop. Remove the metal frame from around the drive, and then grab that plastic connector and pull. I think it should pull right out reveling a SATA connector.

Comment: Besides the advice by @MattClark, you also need to remove the caddy holding the HDD.  *"There are loads of these for desktop (2.5in) drives"* -- Desktop drives are not 2.5", but are 3.5".  Laptop drives are 2.5".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [drive](https://www.fujitsu.com/cn/Images/MHW2160BH.pdf) has a common SATA interface. There are a lot of cases (drive enclosures) both on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=2%205%20sata%20hard%20drive%20enclosure&rt=nc&LH_ItemCondition=3&_trksid=p2045573.m1684) and [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=2%2C5%20drive%20enclousure) for SATA to USB.

From my experience, I would recommend buying SATA to USB 3.0 conversion case/enclosure otherwise you'll experience uncomfortably low read/write speeds.